# Deploy confluent services on Amazon EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, confluent-platform, amazon-eks

I am trying to deploy confluent services on Amazon EKS and I am following this document https://docs.confluent.io/5.3.0/installation/operator/co-deployment.html

After Installing the confluent operator I am trying to install the zookeeper service but the Zookeeper pod is not showing and can't find any logs while executing the below command

```
helm install \
-f ./providers/aws.yaml \
--name zookeeper \
--namespace operator \
--set zookeeper.enabled=true \
./confluent-operator
```

Comment: You can install all components based on the https://docs.confluent.io/operator/current/co-deployment.html this reference page . Please share what is there in ./providers/aws.yaml